# Ho do I replace None with -1?

Tags: python

So, the task is to multiply n-th power of the element in the array with the index n. If n is outside of the array, then return -1. I can't get how to return -1. Sorry for that stupid question from stupid me.

```
def index(array, n):
    for j,i in enumerate(array):
        if j == n:
            res = i**n
            return res
            if res == None:
                return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def index(array, n):
    if len(array)-1<n:
        return -1
    else:
        return array[n]**n
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you need to walk the "array" (I don't know what the actual type is, but I'll assume it is indexable).

```
def index(array, n):
    try:
        v = array[n]
    except IndexError:
        return -1
    return v**n * n
```

I don't know where you think a result of `None` could arise. An out-of-bounds indexing operation raises an exception.

Comment: Tests like these: 
Test.assert_equals(index([1, 2, 3, 4],2),9) (9 is the result which should occur)
Test.assert_equals(index([1, 3, 10, 100],3),1000000) (1000000 is the result which should occur as well)
Test.assert_equals(index([1, 3, 10, 100],9)) -- here's -1

Comment: Oh, I got it. Just without the last "n" things work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that indexing greater than the length of a list will raise `IndexError`.

This code should work (assuming that you mean that n = 1 is the first position):

```
def index(array, n):
    try:
        return array[n - 1] ** n
    except IndexError:
        return -1
```